# How to remove the login screen from MicroXP?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, winlogon

I am programming a project in batch that uses MicroXP. But I need to remove the login screen so it work just after Windows starts.
With login screen I mean this:
[image: The login screen]

Is there a way i can remove or hide it? I tried to search in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: you could set up a scheduled task (as user SYSTEM) and set it to run at boot-up. Not neccessary to "auto-Login" (security reasons...). You can set it to run without any user logged on.

Comment: either via GUI using TaskScheduler or via command line `schtasks /create /?`

Comment: There is no schtasks.exe in MicroXP. Isn't there other way? And actually it needs to auto-login.

Comment: The question should be moved to http://superuser.com

Comment: Try schtasks's predecessor: [at /?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313565).

Comment: There is no at.exe too.